# Linq Any() vs MoveNext()

Tags: c#, linq

Using Linq on collections, which one is best for finding that collection is not empty?

```
HasChild = Childs.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() ? true : false;
```

and

```
HasChild = Childs.Any() ? true : false;
```

Comment: No need to project true/false. `HasChild = Childs.Any()` will do.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: If you'll look at [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1165) of `Any` - that's what it does (try to `MoveNext`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` (and thus can allocate resources) you have to put (in *general case*) not a simple line

```
// Don't do this: it can cause a resource leakage
HasChild = Childs.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() ? true : false;
```

but a fragment

```
bool HasChild = false;

using (var en = Childs.GetEnumerator()) {
  HasChild = en.MoveNext(); // You have no need in ternary operator here
}
```

And it seems *too wordy* when in case of `Any` all you should do

```
bool HasChild = Childs.Any();
```

And `Enumerable<T>.Any` will do the wordy part for you:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0

```
    public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I could have sworn that `Enumerable.Any()` also checks the collection for existence of `Count`, but it seems that `Count()` does that. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1165

Comment: kiziu: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0

Comment: Yes, I know, just an observation. Might possibly lead to microoptimization of `Any`, if someone feels that they might benefit from it.